# I didn't acknowledge someone who helped with my thesis, is there anything I can or should do now?

Tags: thesis, ethics, acknowledgement

I received help with some aspects of my PhD thesis from a tutor (proofreading and graphics). Of the help I received, some mathematical notation they provided made it into my thesis.

However, I did not acknowledge the tutor in the PhD thesis for this help (since received).

Is there anything I could (or should) do to rectify this?

Comment: Flowers? Chocolates? Offers of a return favour?

Comment: Do you see this as a politeness issue or as an issue of scientific ethics? I.e., are you concerned about making the other one angry for not mentioning them or about being accused of having infringed against good practices by not citing/mentioning the contribution of this person?

Comment: @Benedikt Bauer: This question is about academic ethics. The help was not intended to be with the research itself, but mathematical notation and plotting routines in code can be interpreted as such.

Answer (score 20):

If ever the thesis is published elsewhere, say as a paper in a journal or a conference, or perhaps as a technical report, include the name of the person there.

Comment: If allowed for his thesis, would it then be a good idea to upload it with a revised acknowledgement on arxiv?

Comment: @Lilienthal, I understand that the arXiv clearly handles revisions (linking to earlier versions and dating all of them) so I think doing what you suggest would not be a problem.

Comment: So it would also work if he had already uploaded it before? Good to know.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with arXiv, but I understand that it would work.  If the OP uploaded it another way, then perhaps the revisions won't be handled correctly.

Comment: @Lilienthal, by the way, your comment also seems to be relevant to Dave Rose's answer.

Answer (score 14):

It's probably not a huge deal.  Not many people read theses and probably even fewer scan the acknowledgements.  In the worst case you might figuratively have stepped on the persons toes.  I would send them an e-mail or perhaps a postcard with apologies for forgetting to mention them.  That probably suffices — their career is not going to depend on you mentioning them in the acknowledgements.

Answer (score 12):

You might be able to edit the acknowledgement section of the electronic version of you thesis. Contact the university library yourself or through the postgraduate student service.

Comment: good workaround. It can appear in the errata section